# Formula for the sum of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm using a book for my AS Level maths which says that:

"The general rule for the sum of a geometric series is
$$S_n = a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$
or
$$S_n= a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$  "

Why are there two formulas and when do I use each?

Thanks so much, I'm really confused!

Sami x

Comment: Thanks Parisa- I'm new at using the site! :)

Comment: They are the same ; multiply numerator and denominator by $-1$ to pass from one to the other

Comment: The general rule only applies if $r \neq 1$.  If $r = 1$, then $S_n = na$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same formula, the only difference is that you take out a $-1$ at the numerator and at the denominator so they turn into $1$ which is obv not written.
Let me show you:

$S_n=\frac {a(r^n-1)} {r-1}=\frac {(-1)a(1-r^n)} {r-1}=\frac {(-1)a(1-r^n)} {(-1)(1-r)}=\frac {a(1-r^n)} {(1-r)}$

Comment: Sorry if i'm being really dim- I'm trying to teach myself and can't always manage it!

Comment: Vote mine as answer if you find it complete, btw is always a pleasure to help.